# Настроить в apache subdomain по маске

Tags: apache

Помогите настроить такую логику, при запросе mysite.ru должен отображаться контент из var/www/mysite.ru. При запросе *.mysite.ru контент из var/www/subdomain (где * это любой поддомен, вроде admin.mysite.ru).

Пробую так. Пока не работает:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin support@mysite.ru
    ServerName mysite.ru
    ServerAlias *.mysite.ru
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.ru

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=mysite.ru
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mysite\.ru$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /var/www/subdomain/$1 [L]

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```